# Scrollbar on a div should appear only if it has more than 30 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container div which contains other divs(list items).
The size of this container div should equal heights of 30 items.
If there are more than 30 items in container div, it should stay the same size, but show vertical scrollbar.

Question:

> Is there a way to style this container div by CSS so that only after more than 30 list items will be added, the scroll would appear?
>    Or I have to "hardcode" the height of the container div in CSS which would be list_item*30. Or other possibility: use JavaScript to dynamically change height of
>   container on initialization depending on list item height. Are these are the only correct
>   ways to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume your div's inside the container are having a dynamic height? or are they all of the same height? if they are dynamic you have to use javascript, like checking how many list items exist and set an overflow auto or scroll if its more than 30. If the height is the same for every element you can just give the container div the height of items*30 and set the overflow property via css

Comment: In reality they are the same... I was just curious if there is an other way without setting parent height to list_item*30. Because after that if someone changes list_item height, he would also have to change parent container height.
Thank you, gulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention CSS height to parent div and overflow-y to scroll.

here i take two divs height for parent div.

Example Here

```
enter code here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2C7qH/

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. If height of item is known - CSS(your jsfiddle). 
If not - JavaScript should be used. Seems like these are the only ways, no CSS magic this time. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle. Just go through it. Here also I mentioned for just 2 inner divs. If you want to 30 divs height multiply innerDivHeight with 30 instead of 2.

Comment: This fiddle link give you exactly what you are waiting

http://jsfiddle.net/fNdj6/5/

Comment: Thank you for all jsfiddles, Srinu!

Comment: enter code here is no code. you have to add the code to your post. it's requiered for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If every item in the list has the same height "hardcoding" might be the easier way to do this. Just set a height of item_height*30 to the div and have `overflow:auto`.